# Is there a way to change the date of an order?

Tags: magento-2.1, orders

We had some minor technical issues a few days ago, and the final fix for us is to re-do several sales that were done via our storefront. However, since they were done in the past, does anybody know of a way to process an order with the old date applied to it?

Answer (score 0):

You can change it with order repository.
Example:

```
protected $_searchCriteriaBuilder;
protected $_orderRepository;

public function __construct(Template\Context $context,
                            SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
                            OrderRepository $orderRepository,
                            array $data = [])

{
    $this->_searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function modifyOrderDate()
{
    //use search criteria builder to add your filter
    //with incrementid  for example addFilter('increment_id', '000000001','gt')->create();
    // with created at addFilter('created_at', '2017-02-14 00:34:50', 'gt')->create(); and so on
    // depending your needs
    $searchCriteria = $this->_searchCriteriaBuilder
        ->addFilter('entity_id', '1', 'gt')->create();
    //orderList will have the result (collection), cause we use getList
    $orderList = $this->_orderRepository->getList($searchCriteria);

    //literate over result 
    foreach($orderList as $ord){
        //change date
        $ord->setCreatedAt('2017-01-18 00:34:50');
        // use order repository to save
        $this->_orderRepository->save($ord);
    }
    //tested it in a block to verify results in Template, not necessary depending your needs
    return $orderList;
}
```

Depending your need you may have to change dates in payment and shipping ...
See [DevDocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/design-patterns.html) about service contracts and repository interface